# How to prevent functions running if input value is empty or null? Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like this list to only add list items and update the count if the user input, saved as variable 'x,' is not empty or null.  However, the addNewItem() and updateCount() functions seem to be running regardless of what the input value is.

```
const title = document.getElementById('title');
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const input = document.getElementById('todoInput');
const add = document.getElementById('add')


function todoList() {
  var x = document.querySelector('#todoInput').value;
  
  function checkInput(){
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        var p = document.createElement("P")
        var emptyError = document.createTextNode("Please enter something for the list");
        document.querySelector('#message').appendChild(emptyError);
            }
        }
  checkInput();


    
    function removeMsg() {
        const elems = document.querySelector('#message');
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.querySelector("#message").innerHTML = "";
        }, 4000);
      }
    removeMsg();
    
    if (x !== null || x !== "") {
        function addNewItem() {
                console.log('something');
                const item = input.value;
                const text = document.createTextNode(item);
                const newItem = document.createElement('li');
                const check = document.createElement('span');
                check.className = 'circle';
                newItem.appendChild(check);
                newItem.appendChild(text);
                list.appendChild(newItem);
                input.value = '';
                
            }   
        addNewItem();

        function updateCount() {
                const count = list.childElementCount;
                title.innerHTML = `You have ${count} to-dos.`;
            }

        updateCount();
    
        }
    }

todoList();
```

Comment: `x !== null || x !== ""` will always be evaluated to `true`

Answer (score 1):

You can check with `if (x != null && x != "")` to check against empty or null values. However you can also do like this:

`if(x)`

This will ensure if the value of x are not just non-empty and not-null, but also check against all the *falsy* values such as `NaN`, `undefined` etc and will only only the *truthy* values to pass in.

Comment: the && fixed it! Thanks so much, this had been driving me crazy!

Comment: I suggest checking with `if(x)` which is short and simple. Plus it will guard against the other falsy values too. Keep in mind however that `0` is a falsy value too.